# Am I eligible to VAT refund if I buy electronics at duty free stores (specifically Dubai)?

Tags: duty-free, tax-refunds

I'm a citizen of European country.

I'm going to visit Dubai.

I plan to buy some electronics at Dubai duty free stores.

Am I eligible to VAT return?

I know I can request VAT returns if I buy goods up-country. But is it the case if things are bought in duty free stores?

Comment: Generally duty free shops are already VAT free.

Answer (score 5):

The United Arab Emirates has not yet instituted a GST refund system for tourists, although one was approved about a month ago and is expected to go into place sometime in the future.

Once this occurs it is likely that GST refunds will be available for purchases made at duty free stores on arrival into the UAE, which do currently include GST.

Purchases made at Duty Free stores on departure (or transit) do NOT currently include GST, and thus obviously no GST refund would be available.